# HP Envy m6 Subwoofer Beats Audio not working

Tags: pulseaudio, hp, alsa, realtek

I have an HP Envy [m6-n010dx](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c04223655#AbT1).Running Elementary(Ubuntu 14.04)This is an AMD based model,which includes Beats Audio in the form of 2 speakers and an integrated subwoofer.
It uses Realtek ALC3241 sound card/chip.I can not get the subwoofer to work at all,and the sound is laughable compaired to Beats on Windows 8.
I have read many posts regarding this and have tried many of the suggestions,such as adding options snd-hda-intel model=ref to alsa-base.conf,enabled lfe remixing,
and changed the amount of sample channels.WHen using HDAJackRetask,I set one of the unconected pins to LFE Speaker,and Alsamixer shows a bass speaker that can be muted or unmuted,but there is no volume level for it,and no change to my sound.Depending on the pins I connect,different things show up in alsamixer,but they have no volume levels,only mute or output.I feel like I've tried everything,and any help would be appreiated.Let me know if you'd like to see my aplay or lspci | Audio outputs.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did to solve my issue with the subwoofer.

1. I searched for ALSA Tools in software manager. Do note, ALSA Tools now have HDAJackRetask packed into it.
2. I installed ALSA Tools from the search result. Fired up HDAJackRetask. Selected ALC3241. Here I noticed my Pin IDs were set up as below:

Pin 0x12 = internal mic
Pin 0x14 = internal speaker
Pin 0x15 = headphone
Pin 0x1a = microphone

3. To activate the subwoofer, all I had to do is select 'Show unconnected pins', override Pin ID: 0x17 to Internal speaker(LFE) and click apply now. I checked the sound output using VLC/Rythmbox/Videos. Finally I clicked Install boot override to make the setting permanent.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, what type of laptop are you using just out of curiosity? I have actually stopped using the HP Envy that I was having this issue on, and I have moved onto a newer Envy model, but it doesn't include a subwoofer. But I may try to replicate your suggestion on the previous machine.

Answer (score 0):

My Configuration:

> Laptop: Asus Zenbook UX51VZA
>   Realtek ALC663
>   OS: Ubuntu 14.04.3 (lsb_release -a), kernel: 3.019.031 (uname -r)

Speakers: just the internal one and the subwoofer

Problem: External subwoofer doesn't work or not recognized

Resolution:

a. Add line at the bottom of alsa-base.conf

```
`sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`
line at bottom-->   
      options snd-hda-intel model=auto
```

b. No need to change anything in /etc/pulse/default.pa

c. Edit daemon.conf file

```
sudo gedit /etc/pulse/daemon.conf
--> take out the ";" and change to yes for this line
```

enable-lfe-remixing = yes

```
also, unmark line/edit/or add as necessary in order to have
```

default-channel-map = front-left,front-right,lfe

(note: if your speaker configuration is different, ie, you have rear speakers, etc, add those in, such as rear-left, rear-right...)

---

if you only have your internal laptop speaker and the subwoofer -------------

d. Add below block of lines to extra-hdmi.conf file

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/profile-sets/extra-hdmi.conf

[Mapping analog-surround-21]
device-strings = surround40:%f
channel-map = front-left,front-right,lfe
paths-output = analog-output analog-output-speaker analog-output-desktop-speaker
priority = 7
direction = output


sudo gedit /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/profile-sets/default.conf
```

...add here same block as above

1. Install pavucontrol 
   `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`
2. Install alsa-utils-gui

   sudo apt-get install alsa-utils-gui
3. Install hdajackretask

   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:diwic/hda && sudo apt-get update

   sudo apt-get install hda-jack-retask

type this command in the terminal:

hdajackretask

select/checkmark "Show unconnected pins", checkmark 'Advanced Override'
    Go down to 'Not Connected', Pin 0x16,  select Location: External, Device: Speaker, Jack:Other Analog, Channel: 5, Channel Group: 'Center (LFE). Click Apply Now.
    Now Unselect Advanced Override. Go back through the list until you reach Pin 0x16. It should be checked, but the option shows blank. Choose INTERNAL SPEAKER (LFE) from the Drop-down list. Click Apply now and Install boot override.

NOTE: to check your possible pin setting for the subwoofer, get this:

```
 sudo apt-get install snd-hda-tools

    then type command:  sudo hda-jack-sense-test -as
```

(first with subwoofer plugged in, ...look for a YES in the pin line, then with the subwoofer disconnected)

```
NOTE2: mine showed the subwoofer when connected as being on pin 0x1e. But, I decided to leave it on pin 0x16.
```

REBOOT computer.

4. Open Pavucontrol

   - go to Configuration tab and choose 'Analog Surround 2.1 Output + Analog Input' (or if you have other configuration, like front/rear speaker, than 4.1, or front/center/rear 5.1, etc)
   - go to Output Devices and Select 'Speakers' in the dropdown option 'PORT'.  Adjust your volumes as necessary
5. Check alsamixer volumes, especially the Master and BASS ones. Move across options with right arrow key. If you see MM for a device, press 'M' to unmute. Then up arrow key to raise volume
   ---> type command :   alsamixer

Good luck.

Comment: One correction:
[Mapping analog-surround-21]
device-strings = surround40:%f
channel-map = front-left,front-right,lfe, lfe

Note : added another lfe to channel-map. You will have 2 subwoofer levels showing, but you can just reduce the subwoofer left to zero and work with just subwoofer right level

Also, in step 3, in advanced override, Location is Internal, not External

Comment: Thank you for your reply,I will test this when I get home.I'll let you know how it turns out.

Comment: Great. Hope it works for you.

Comment: "if you only have your internal laptop speaker and the subwoofer -------------

d. Add below block of lines to extra-hdmi.conf file" ,I'm not sure I understand.I have 2 speaksers and a sub.I also have an HDMI out as well.

Comment: by the way this is the output hda-jack-sense-test -as.  Pin 0x03 (Unknown Digital Out): present = No
Pin 0x05 (Not connected): present = No
Pin 0x07 (Not connected): present = No
Pin 0x09 (Not connected): present = No
Pin 0x0b (Not connected): present = No
Pin 0x0d (Not connected): present = No  And,also you say with the subwoofer plugged in,but this is an integrated subwoofer I'm trying to get working.

Comment: sorry about the massive amount of comments.I thought I should mentions that after setting pin0x16 in hda-jack-retask,when I applied,and unchecked advanced override options,it was selected but there was still a drop down menu with the options listed.

Comment: I installed the overide,hda-jack-sense still reported nothing present,and still no 2.1 channel in pavu.I'll triple check all the steps again when I get a chance.

Comment: My laptop only has the internal speaker (left/right channels) and an external subwoofer which I attach to a 2.5mm jack.  Thus, I needed a 2.1 surround configuration.  In your case, if you have internal + external speakers, you would have a 4.1 surround, or probably 5.1 with HDMI added in (thus you wouldn't need to add the 2.1 mentioned above) In the port options of pavucontrol you should be able to see an HDMI option to switch to.

Comment: In hdajackretask, the is SPDIF out option on pin 0x1e.  If it is the subwoofer that is on HDMI, than you can assign it to this pin.  Just as explained above, except different pin.   And in Advanced Override, I would choose either SPDIF out or Digital Out in the Device setting dropdown.

Comment: I just saw you other comment about the internal subwoofer. So are all the speakers internal?  Or 2 external and 1 internal sub? Try to put the sub on either pin 0x1e or the 0x03 (me, I only have 0x13 showing, actually, 0x11 and above).  Choose SPDIF or Digital out in Advanced, then return to hadjackretask,, uncheck advanced, and scroll down to the pin chosen, and again, choose SPDIF out.  Apply.  Install Boot options.  THen reboot.  Don't forget to also check out ALSAMIXER (small letter in terminal though) to make sure the sub is not muted.

Comment: All internal,2 top left and rights,and an integrated subwoofer on the bottom of it.I have seen other how to's where they used hda-jack-retask to get their subwoofer working,but they had 4 speakers and a sub,and their sound chip was different than mine.I've tried enaling all of the disabled pins,but it's never ended up working.After following your guide I did get 2.1 working but all the channels seem to only control the left and right sound.Alsamixer shows  a bass speaker with OO but there is no level slider to adjust it. I really appreciate you trying to help, any ideas?

Comment: In alsamixer,  press F5 to view all channels. You move across the channels using the --> right arrow keyboard key; if MM shows, type M to unmute; while on a channel, press up arrow key/or down arrow key to adjust volume.