# Ubuntu 17.10 Unable to find beats audio driver for Hp Envy 15 k020us

Tags: drivers, sound, 17.10, hp, realtek

Recently I installed Ubuntu 17.10 on my laptop along with Windows 10. My laptop model number is Hp Envy 15 k020us and sound card driver is from Realtek audio.  All things are ok instead of 1, Audio. I have beats audio feature on my laptop. When I play music, I can hear but the sound is not good which I get on windows 10. I tried several solutions from the internet (such as the solution for Intel audio), but could not do better. The sound is really bad. Please give me any suggestion. I love Ubuntu and I used it on my previous laptop. How to fix the audio. Please give me any solution. I will be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the best solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/675012/hp-envy-m6-subwoofer-beats-audio-not-working) which worked with my audio driver. Seems it happened because the subwoofer was not working. So I had to manually activate it. 
My Audio Driver is Realtek ALC3241. The processor is Intel Haswell.
What I did here:

1. Installed `alsa-tools-gui`
2. Run `hdajackretask`
3. Select `Show unconnected pins`
4. Override `Pin ID:0x17` and select `Internal speaker (LFE)`
5. Click `Install boot override`
6. Reboot Ubuntu and the sound was good and working better than before, though not up to the mark

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177885/beatsaudio-driver-for-linux-using-laptop-model-hp-envy-m6) link for a similar issue.

- Install <s>`hda-jack-restack`</s> `alsa-tools-gui` from [this](https://launchpad.net/~diwic/+archive/ubuntu/hda) link.
- Once you've installed this, you can start `hda-jack-retask` from the shell: `hdajackretask`
- After this, you have to do some manual pin configuration which is covered in the attached link. Once you go through with everything, you should have pretty great audio.

I myself have used this method on Ubuntu 18.04, and can verify that it does, indeed, work.